# Show that vectors are linearly independent vectors for each value of a

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

"Show that $(a \ \ 3)$ and $(2 \ \ \ 1-a)$ are linearly independent vectors for each value of a"

This means that given scalars $C1,C2$ their scalar sum should equal $0$:

$aC1 + 2C2 = 0$

$3C1 + C2-aC2 = 0$

$\Rightarrow 6C1 - aC1 + a^2C1 = 0.$

Don't know what I need to do now or if this is wrong already.

Comment: Regarding $a$ as an unknown constant, you have two unknowns, $C_1$ and $C_2,$ and two equations. Solve for $C_1$ and $C_2.$ Your turn.

Comment: Yes, it's fine. Now factor that last result. If $C_1 \ne 0$, then what must be true? Finally, assuming the base field is $\mathbb{R}$, what can you conclude?

Comment: Ah which means that  $(6 - a + a^2) = 0$, but that has no real solution?

Comment: Right -- check the discriminant.

Comment: Which is negative so it has two complex answers, what do I do with this fact?

Comment: Then for real $a$, $(6 - a + a^2) \ne 0$. But you know the product
$$C_1(6 - a + a^2) = 0$$
If a product of two quantities is zero, but one of the quantities is not equal to zero, then ...

Comment: Then  $C_1$ is obviously 0? I still don't understand how that is proof :/

Edit: So because both  $C_1 $ and  $C_2 $ should not both be zero, there  will be no solution which means that they are linearly independent for any a?

Comment: You are trying to prove that $C_1$ and $C_2$ must _both_ be zero. You've shown $C_1 = 0$. Plug that back into the first equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is workable. As for the comment where you got $\Rightarrow$ from one solves the first equation for $C_2 = -aC_1/2$ and inserts that in the second equation. What you're basically doing here is a proof by contradiction - you assume that there is a (non-trivial) linear combination of the vectors that's $0$.

The requirement is also $C_1$ and $C_2$ should not both be zero. You know that if one is zero the other must be zero for the sum to be zero. So you basically know that this requires $C_1\ne 0$. So you can divide both sides with $C_1$ and get the equation:

$$\left(a-{1\over2}\right)^2 + {23\over4} = \left(a-{1\over2}\right)^2 - {1\over4} + 6 = a^2 - a + 6 = 0$$

Which isn't possible with real $a$ since $(a-1/2)^2\ge 0$ and $23/4>0$ so the LHS (left hand side) is certainly greater than zero and not equal to zero. Now as we see that the equation is certainly false for all $a$ we have a contradiction an we can conclude that our assumption that theres a (non-trivial) linear combination is false.

That is whatever value of $a$ we have no (non-trivial) linear combination of the vectors that's the null vector.

Comment: What is LHS? So this means the equation can't be 0 for any real a, so what do I do with this fact?

Comment: LHS=Left Hand Side

Comment: The equation is a consequence of the assumption that $C_1$ and $C_2$ are constants to form a linear combination. This puts an requirement on $a$ that is impossible to fulfill. This means that there can't be such a linear combination. The equation is an equation for which values of $a$ the vectors become linearly dependent, without any solution it will be linearly independent for all $a$.